# How do I write a Python list out to a file?

Tags: python, file, list

I'm trying to write a list of strings to a file in Python. The problem I have when doing this is the look of the output. I want to write the contents of the lists without the list structures.

This is the part of the code that is writing the list to the file:

```
loglengd = len(li)
runs = 0
while loglengd > runs:
    listitem = li[runs]
    makestring = str(listitem)
    print (makestring)
    logfile.write(makestring + "\n")
    runs = runs +1
print("done deleting the object")
logfile.close()
```

The output this is giving me looks like this:

```
['id:1\n']
['3\n']
['-3.0\n']
['4.0\n']
['-1.0\n']
['id:2\n']
['3\n']
['-4.0\n']
['3.0\n']
['-1.0\n']
['id:4\n']
['2\n']
['-6.0\n']
['1.0\n']
['-1.0\n']
```

and this is what it is supposed to look like:

```
id:1
3
-3.0
4.0
-1.0
id:2
3
-4.0
3.0
-1.0
id:4
2
-6.0
1.0
-1.0
```

Comment: *lock* at this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11003325/236871), they seem pretty similar. duplicate?

Comment: @KurzedMetal That's not nice. :) and they're not similar... (here OP wants to write, and there, "delete" some lines)

Comment: no they ain't, not at all. the first question is about how to delete a part of a file. this one is on how to remove the "['\n']" part of an output when writing a file from a list. in fact they are two different questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please learn how to use loops (http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)
2. `li` seems to be a list of lists, instead of a list of strings. Therefore you must use `listitem[0]` to get the string.

If you just want to write the text to a file:

```
text='\n'.join(listitem[0] for listitem in li)
logfile.write(text)
logfile.close()
```

if you also want to do something in the loop:

```
for listitem in li:
    logfile.write(listitem[0] + '\n')
    print listitem[0]
logfile.close()
```

Comment: I do now how to use them, but what I diden't realize where the "list inside a list" thing, added this to my while loop and now it works like a shame! so thx!
    liste = listitem[0]
    makestring = str(liste)

Comment: @user1229391: in general, if you're initializing a separate integer for loop control and checking it against the length of your iterable in Python, you're Doing It Wrong(tm).

Comment: hmm, may be true, but it works for me so in this chase I can't se why it shud be wrong?

Comment: @user1229391: because it's a Rube Goldberg contraption - it does the job in a needlessly complicated way.

Comment: @user1229391: see The Zen of Python (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): '**Simple is better than complex.**', '**Readability counts.**' and '**There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.**'. If there is a simpler way to do it, you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for s in (str(item[0]) for item in li):
    print(s)
    logfile.write(s+'\n')

print("done deleting the object")
logfile.close()
```

Comment: Why is there a print statement indicating an object is deleted? Is that the logfile.close() ?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: because this is what his loop should have been, in idiomatic Python, and because that is how he finished off.

Answer (score -2):

The string function you are searching for is strip().

It works like this:

```
logs = ['id:1\n']
text = logs[0]
text.strip()
print(text)
```

So I think you need to write it like this:

```
loglengd = len(li)
runs = 0
while loglengd > runs:
    listitem = li[runs]
    makestring = str(listitem)
    print (makestring.strip())     #notice this
    logfile.write(makestring + "\n")
    runs = runs +1
print("done deleting the object")
logfile.close()
```

Comment: `strip()` won't get rid of the `[` and `]` characters in the output file.